# Is there a way to check the cloud credits consumed by every reconstruction (photoscene_id) on the Autodesk Forge Reality Capture API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I run several reconstructions per day using the ReCap API and I would like to know if there is a way to identify the number of cloud credits consumed by each of them. Is there a way to check this, is it linked to the photoscene ID? 
- I try looking at the Usage Analysis and it adds up all my credits consumed per day.
- The GET photoscene details end point gives me just the aws_hourly_rate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not right now but we’ve got internal APIs for such purposes and they could be released for public access in the near future. Stay tuned to our [Forge Blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog) for announcements.